# How can I remove all the users and groups associated with removed (purged) programs?

Tags: apt, uninstall, users, groups

How can I remove all the users and groups associated with removed (purged) programs?

For example, I install exim. It created a group and a user named Debian-exim.

I then use it for a while, and remove it using `apt-get purge exim*`. And then, it removes all the files associated with it. But, it does not remove the users and groups created by the program 'exim'. I have installed and removed several programs, so, I am not sure how many users are left behind in my system. I want to remove all the unwanted users automatically when I uninstall a program, and I also want to remove all  the unwanted users that exist currently in my system. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The problem is that no program can determine which users are unwanted (by you). If a user created by a package is removed when purging the package is up to the package maintainer. I'm not sure about debian, but on fedora it is best practice to _not_ remove users, I guess it's the same with debian packaging. The reason is that it is perfectly possible to have files not removed on package removal (think of e.g. databases). If the user was removed upon package removal, you would end up with files without an owner, and you wouldn't even know who created those files.

Comment: @danzel, so it would cause permission problems??

Comment: Thanks mate, you could post it as an answer though.

Comment: **I also removed some users manually. So, I think I should consider running**: *`find / -nogroup -nouser`*

And, I should remove them, or give me a ownership for the ones that make sense. I am pretty sure I have not yet messed up my Ubuntu Installtion :)

Comment: That would be reasonable because you could get into trouble if you reinstalled the package and the newly created user has a different uid. I would also suggest searching for files owned by a user before deleting it in the future.

Comment: I'm just gonna reinstall Ubuntu, im done with this LMAO